# Arduino Serial Read when disconnected

Tags: c++, api, arduino, communication

I am developing a racing simulator, and I have a problem. I have a C++ program that sends data to Arduino. Arduino receives it, parses the string and one of those substrings must be displayed in a TFT. I have noticed that the Arduino only prints the value in the TFT when the C++ program finishes, so it only prints the value when the `Serial.read()` function returns false. How can I get the live data, to print the live values?

Here I bring you the Arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <UTFTGLUE.h>
UTFTGLUE myGLCD(0x9488, A5, A4, A3, A2, A0);

char lastgear = '0';
extern uint8_t Bigfont[];
String sParams[3];
int iCount, i;
String sLine;

void setup() {
  randomSeed(analogRead(5));   //.kbv Due does not like A0
  pinMode(A0, OUTPUT);       //.kbv mcufriend have RD on A0
  digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);

  // Set up the LCD
  myGLCD.InitLCD();
  myGLCD.clrScr();
  myGLCD.setFont(BigFont);
  myGLCD.setTextSize(5);
  myGLCD.print("  Victor Casado", LEFT, 15);
  delay(500);
  myGLCD.clrScr();
  myGLCD.setTextSize(24);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // reading the line from file
    sLine = Serial.readString();
    // parse only if exists
    if (sLine.length() > 0) {
      // parse the line
      iCount = StringSplit(sLine, ',', sParams, 3);
      // print the extracted paramters
      for (i = 0; i < iCount; i++) {
        Serial.print(sParams[i]);
        myGLCD.setColor(255, 255, 255);
        myGLCD.print(sParams[0], 200, 75);
      }
      Serial.println("");
    }
  }
}

int StringSplit(String sInput, char cDelim, String sParams[], int iMaxParams) {
  int iParamCount = 0;
  int iPosDelim, iPosStart = 0;

  do {
    // Searching the delimiter using indexOf()
    iPosDelim = sInput.indexOf(cDelim, iPosStart);
    if (iPosDelim > (iPosStart + 1)) {
      // Adding a new parameter using substring()
      sParams[iParamCount] = sInput.substring(iPosStart, iPosDelim - 1);
      iParamCount++;
      // Checking the number of parameters
      if (iParamCount >= iMaxParams) {
        return (iParamCount);
      }
      iPosStart = iPosDelim + 1;
    }
  } while (iPosDelim >= 0);
  if (iParamCount < iMaxParams) {
    // Adding the last parameter as the end of the line
    sParams[iParamCount] = sInput.substring(iPosStart);
    iParamCount++;
  }
  return (iParamCount);
}
```

I have tried to change this part:

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
  // reading the line from file
  sLine = Serial.readString();
  // parse only if exists
  if (sLine.length() > 0) {
    // parse the line
    iCount = StringSplit(sLine, ',', sParams, 3);
    // print the extracted paramters
    for (i = 0; i < iCount; i++) {
      Serial.print(sParams[i]);
      myGLCD.setColor(255, 255, 255);
      myGLCD.print(sParams[0], 200, 75);
    }
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

To this, and it works the same:

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
  // reading the line from file
  sLine = Serial.readString();
  // parse only if exists
  if (sLine.length() > 0) {
    // parse the line
    iCount = StringSplit(sLine, ',', sParams, 3);
    // print the extracted paramters
    for (i = 0; i < iCount; i++) {
      Serial.print(sParams[i]);
    }
    Serial.println("");
  }
  myGLCD.setColor(255, 255, 255);
  myGLCD.print(sParams[0], 200, 75);
}
```

And this:

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
  // reading the line from file
  sLine = Serial.readString();
  // parse only if exists
  if (sLine.length() > 0) {
    // parse the line
    iCount = StringSplit(sLine, ',', sParams, 3);
    // print the extracted paramters
    for (i = 0; i < iCount; i++) {
      Serial.print(sParams[i]);
    }
    Serial.println("");
    myGLCD.setColor(255, 255, 255);
    myGLCD.print(sParams[0], 200, 75);
  }
}
```

Hope you can help me!

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to use `Serial.readStringUntil()` to only read a string until a specific terminator character, not until the stream ends (the program finishes)

Comment: `Serial.read()` can't return false. It returns integers.

Comment: Hi, I tried with the readStringUntil, and it works perfectly catching the data, but it doesn't refresh the serial, so when the first input is for example "2", it keeps showing "2", despite of the change of the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Serial.readString()` it tries to read until it gets a timeout.
The default timeout on serial is 1 sec. That means that after the last character has been read, it waits 1 sec. more before it finishes. You can set the timeout value manually in the setup by using `Serial.setTimeout(10);` right after `Serial.begin()` or as @Sami suggested, you can use `Serial.readStringUntil("xxx")` where 'xxx' is the end of the string that you send fx. '\n' or '\r\n' if you terminate the string with a linebreak.

Comment: Hi, I tried with the readStringUntil, and it works perfectly catching the data, but it doesn't refresh the serial, so when the first input is for example "2", it keeps showing "2", despite of the change of the value of the variable.